# JavaScript forms and functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a simple random number generator, where you input 3 integers into forms. The program then returns a certain amount of random numbers between the other two values. When I open the page the forms are displayed but when I click the button to generate the random numbers nothing happens. Why is this happening?

```
<html>
<head>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">


    function randomFromTo(from, to)
    {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * ((to - from) + 1) + from);
    }
function include(arr, obj)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
    {
    if (arr[j] == obj) return true;
    }
}
    function RandomGen(form)
    {
    var enteries = new Array();
    var number = form.from.value;
    var top = form.top.value;
    var size = form.inputBox.value;
    var count;
    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        var num = randomFromTo(number, top);
        if (include(enteries, num) == true)
        {
            count--;
        }
        else
        {
            enteries[count] = num;
        }
    }
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i <= enteries.length; i++)
    {
        document.write(enteries[i]);
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}


</script>
</head>

<body>

<center><h1>Random Number Generator</h1></center>
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET">Enter the Range of Values
<input type="text" name = "from" value="">to
<input type="text" name = "top" value="">
<p>Enter The Amount of Random Numbers Needed
<input type="text" name = "inputBox" value=""><p>
<input type="button" name="button" value="Generate" onClick=RandomGen(this.form)">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: first change your script tag to `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: @Timster onClick=RandomGen(this.form)" missing ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error here

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="Generate" onClick=RandomGen(this.form)">
```

should be

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="Generate" onClick="RandomGen(this.form)">
```

Also this part should be updated, not because it will cause an error but because it is 2011

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

### Update

Or:

```
<script>
```

no need for the type attribute because it is 2018!

Answer (score 0):

You missed a quote:

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="Generate" onClick="RandomGen(this.form)">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="RandomGen(this.form)"
```

That part of your code was malformed. `onclick` is always all lower case and you were missing a `"`

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a "

```
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Generate" onClick="RandomGen(this.form)">
```